# How to convert numFmt from excel to regex, or mso-number-format to css?

Tags: javascript, css, regex, excel, exceljs

I'm developing an enhancement for a MERN application. Using exceljs lib to read the excel file, which gives us assortment of APIs. In particular, I'm asking about the style attributes.

It seems date and currency both use a style: { numFmt: <> }} in excel. We have to display in a HTML table the same format. Is there any utility that will convert an excel style to css style or even specifically, numFmt to a regex that we could accomplish the same formatting in excel and the HTML table?

Right now I am just handling scenarios found in our template, but obviously this is not a scalable solution. In this example, we are accomodating for USD currency only adding commas, and putting () in case of (-)

```
// This is just 1 scenario
// nmbFmt (excel) : _("$"* #,##0_);_("$"* (#,##0);_("$"* "-"?_);_(@_)
case '_("$"* #,##0_);_("$"* (#,##0);_("$"* "-"?_);_(@_)':
    resCol = resCol.toString().split( /(?=(?:\d{3})+(?:\.|$))/g )
        .join( ",").replace(/-(.*)/, "($1)")
    break;
```

Original:  505000000
Expected:  $505,000,000

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam

Comment: @Pete - How would you suggest a change to the question? I'm asking for any utility to try. This could even be a home bred function.

Comment: Not sure, I just knopw that specifically asking for a "utility" is off topic, and asking for someones function is off topic as it would be too broad.   https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.  If your code is currently working, perhaps it's best to post it on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and see if they can make it better?

Comment: No, my solution is not scalable, I cannot copy and paste every possible nmbFmt from excel into a switch-case. Thanks for the suggestions, but I feel this question meets the requirements under "What topics can I ask about here?"